# Angular Unit testing : Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I Am working on unit testing under my angular 15 app. I am getting the below error while running the test:

Error: Cannot match any routes.URL Segment: 'signin'

Below is the unit test code for my component:

```
 fdescribe('ExtensionListComponent',()=>{
   BeforeEach(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
       imports: [
        RouteTestingModule.withRoutes([{
        path: 'extensions-list',
       component: ExtensionListComponent}]),
       HttpClientTestingModule
       ],
       declarations:[
       ExtensionListComponent
       ],
       providers: [
       TaskService
       ]
  }).compileComponents();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is trying to navigate to `login`. You need to define your `signin` Path here:

```js
   RouteTestingModule.withRoutes([
      {
        path: 'extensions-list',
        component: ExtensionListComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'signin',
       component: SigninComponentProbably
      }
  ]),
```

Or fake the login access somehow.

Comment: This should be: `{ path: 'extension-list', component: ExtensionListComponent }, { path: 'signin', component: SignInComponentProbably }`

Comment: Thank you...It started working once I added the path to signin and its component.